# How do I get The Golden Gift?

Tags: achievements, super-meat-boy

I started playing Super Meat Boy yesterday, and while I was able to beat the first world (Forest) without really any difficulty. Beating the XMas levels are very hard. I'm having a really hard time with the very first board.

- Are the rest of the boards on this christmas world that hard? Harder?
- Any tips for the first board? It requires quite the perfect execution, but maybe I'm doing somewhing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't require perfection, but you can't quit (one play session). Also, FWIW, [it's the wrong achievement](http://twitter.com/SuperMeatBoy/status/152931617369886721), but we'll see if they're going to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the other special gift-awarding christmas achievements were meant to be gentle introductions into their respective games, both of Team Meat's games - Super Meat Boy and the Binding of Isaac, both already incredibly difficult games as it is - chose to pick the most *insanely difficult achievements imaginable*.

So, hopefully you didn't spend too much time trying to get the gift for this achievement, as even for SMB veterans this achievement takes a long time.

Level 3 is insanely easy due to [a glitch that allows you to jump over the walls](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FT5U7LUipVk).  However, assuming you don't want to [cheat](http://steamcheeves.com/winter2011/#supermeatboy), the rest of the levels will just have to be beaten the old fashioned way: thru sweat, tears, and profanity.

Have fun!

Comment: "have to be beaten the old fashioned way: thru sweat, tears, and profanity" love it!

Comment: The Binding of Isaac was not made by Team Meat, only the artist of the duo (Edmund) was involved with Isaac.